# separate start date and end date in symfony 1.4

Tags: php, symfony-1.4

I have a form filter and in symfony 1.4 and i have a widget sfWidgetFormFilterDate

```
'datedepot'           => new sfWidgetFormFilterDate(array('from_date' => new sfWidgetFormDate(), 'to_date' => new sfWidgetFormDate(), 'with_empty' => false)),
```

the problem is i can't separate the start date and end date in the template.

```
<?php echo $filter['datedepot']->render() ?>
```

How i can sep separate the start date and end date in the template ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- you can apply you template for this widget follow https://github.com/nationalfield/symfony/blob/master/lib/widget/sfWidgetFormFilterDate.class.php#L28
- or you can create your widget just extend it from **sfWidgetFormFilterDate** and define your render https://github.com/nationalfield/symfony/blob/master/lib/widget/sfWidgetFormFilterDate.class.php#L60